# How to determine if Latitude is North or South, or Longitude West or East from decimal coordinate?

Tags: php, gps, latitude-longitude

lets say i have this position : `32.709237, 51.627789`
I need to know if its latitude is W or E and longitude is N or S .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Latitude is positive in north and negative in south.
Similarly, Longitude is positive in east and negative in west.

```
if(value<0)
//value is negative
```

Answer (score 3):

```
If 1st value = positive the mean you are in East
If 1st value = negative the mean you are in West
If 2nd value = positive the mean you are in North
If 2nd value = negative the mean you are in South
```